# xmodmap keyboard changes stop working after Logout and Login again

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, autostart, xmodmap

I run Lubuntu 19.10.
To disable "F11" and "Right-click" on the mouse I use xmodmap. I launch this during startup with the Lubuntu Autostart.
For the first login it works fine. After I logout and login again it reload the default keyboard mapping. The "Right-click" is still "disabled".
Here you can see my Xmodmap file.

`keycode 37 =
keycode 64 =
keycode 95 =
pointer = 1 2 99 4 5 6 7 8 9 10`

Here you can see the Autostart file.

`[Desktop Entry]
Exec=/usr/bin/xmodmap keymods
Name=Tasten sperren
Type=Application
Version=1.0`

Any ideas or suggestions ?

Thanks in advance !

Best Regards,
Patrick

Comment: Related: [How to disable multimedia keys entirely? 18.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/q/1200893/968501)

Comment: it is the same with the skript. First login works, second one it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way how it works.

I created a ~/home//startup.sh
This I launch with Autostart from Lubuntu.

`#!/bin/bash
sleep 5
xmodmap keymods &
exit 0`

I need to use a 5 seconds delay.

Comment: Well done! You do not need the `&` and the `exit 0` parts

Comment: Thanks for your help !