# Control ALT Both left and right working as SHIFT

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

My (left/righ) CTR ALT right SHIFT work as left SHIFT.Im on freshly installed ubuntu 19.10 but tested 18.04,Linux Mint 19.3 and  latest Kubuntu. And on each that system same problem presist. On windows everthings working. Any ideas whats going on ??

```
KeyRelease event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x4800001,
root 0x38d, subw 0x0, time 1218059, (-859,134), root:(629,666),
state 0x1, keycode 50 (keysym 0xffe1, Shift_L), same_screen YES,
XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Comment: use `xev` in the terminal to detect the key code for the left alt and remap it to the left alt like so `xmodmap -e 'keycode 00 = Alt_L'` changing the `00` to the detected keycode. and do the same for the others. Then create and use a script to maintain changes following the instructions in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1200910/968501)