# Disable F1 key with keyboard individual feature

Tags: keyboard, function-keys

On my system, F1 disables audio output.

Occasionally pressed without noticing it, is cumbersome in teleconferences.

Is there a way to deactivate that?

Comment: Is this a laptop? Then in the bios, you can set function keys to behave normally. Muting then would be done by pressing a "function" key + F1. Otherwise, you can look to change the key in the Keyboard settings.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable multimedia keys entirely? 18.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1200893/how-to-disable-multimedia-keys-entirely-18-04-lts)

Comment: @Raffa I am not sure I wish to disable all the multimedia keys.

Comment: You do not have to disable all the multimedia keys. You can follow the linked instructions to detect and disable or remap any multimedia key functionality be it one or more.