# Fn key lock of Logitech keyboard

Tags: drivers, keyboard, logitech

I have a Logitech G512 Carbon (wired USB keyboard) and am sick of using the FN key to pause music or adjust the volume. I use Logitech software on Windows to turn on the fn lock to access media keys directly (without holding fn). Is there a way to do this on Ubuntu? I haven't been able to find a solution for this.

EDIT:

Things I tried:

- Solaar
- Bunch of key combinations that are meant to activate fn lock. Looks like this keyboard does not support that

Comment: Does [Fn]+[Esc] not put the keyboard into Fn Lock mode? This works on every Logitech keyboard I've used in the past, though I'll admit to never having used any of the G-series.

Comment: I tried already, it doesn't work :(

Comment: You can remap the function keys and do the **opposite** of [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1200893/how-to-disable-multimedia-keys-entirely-18-04-lts/1200910#1200910) using the tools and methods explained in the same linked answer.

Comment: If you still need help with that, please add a clear picture of the multimedia keys on your keyboard and the output of `xmodmap -pke` to your question.

Comment: I would rather not lose my function keys. This is a hacky way. I guess I will have to do something like this if I cannot find another way.

Comment: You shouldn't loose them. You should remap them to work with *Fn*. I assume that currently *F1, F2,.....,F12* work without *Fn* and *multimedia keys* work with *Fn* and you want the opposite. Right?

Comment: Ahh I see. I will try this out and let you know

Comment: @Raffa Please write this solution as an answer so you can have the bounty :)

Comment: I am glad it worked. I wish I had the chance to help you more although you are so smart you made it work with minimal help. OK I will write an answer for posterity and explain the best way I can.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that currently **function keys <kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>F2</kbd>,.....,<kbd>F12</kbd>** work without **<kbd>Fn</kbd>** and **multimedia keys** work with **<kbd>Fn</kbd>** and you want the opposite.

What you can do in this case is to remap **function keys** to work with **<kbd>Fn</kbd>** and **multimedia keys** to work without **<kbd>Fn</kbd>** by following these steps:

1. Show the current keyboard map by running the following command in the terminal:

```
xmodmap -pke
```

2. Inspect the output and identify lines that contain `XF68...` right after the `=` sign like so:

```
keycode 232 = XF86MonBrightnessDown NoSymbol XF86MonBrightnessDown NoSymbol XF86MonBrightnessDown
```

The above line, for example, shows that the key with code number **232** is currently configured to trigger `XF86MonBrightnessDown` which will decrease the monitor's brightness and you can change this behavior by assigning a different value to it like so `xmodmap -e 'keycode 232 = New_Value'`.

3. Inspect the output and identify lines that contain function keys names `F1, F2, ...., F12` right after the `=` sign like so:

```
keycode  95 = F11 F11 F11 F11 F11 F11 XF86Switch_VT_11 F11 F11 XF86Switch_VT_11 F11 F11 F11 F11 XF86Switch_VT_11
```

The above line, for example, shows that the key with code number **95** is currently configured to trigger `F11` function and you can change this behavior by assigning a different value to it like so `xmodmap -e 'keycode 95 = New_Value'`.

4. Now switch the two keys' values by assigning the **F11** functionality to **key 232** and `XF86MonBrightnessDown` functionality to **key 95** by running the following two commands in the terminal:

**First**,

```
xmodmap -e 'keycode 232 = F11'
```

**Then**,

```
xmodmap -e 'keycode 95 = XF86MonBrightnessDown'
```

5. Do the same for all the multimedia and function keys to reflect what you see on your keyboard.

---

The new functionality will be effective immediately. This change in functionality will, however, be lost after reboot or logout/login.

To preserve the change after reboots and logouts/logins, you will need to do the following:

1. Create and edit a script file in your home directory by running the following command in the terminal:

```
nano ~/.Modify_Multimedia_Keys.sh
```

2. Add this `#!/bin/bash` in the first line then add your `xmodmap -e 'keycode Number = New_Value'` commands below the first line ( each command in a single new line ) like so:

```
#!/bin/bash
xmodmap -e 'keycode 232 = F11'
xmodmap -e 'keycode 95 = XF86MonBrightnessDown'
```

3. Save the script file and exit the editor by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> then press <kbd>Y</kbd>.
4. Make the script file executable by running the following command in the terminal:

```
chmod +x ~/.Modify_Multimedia_Keys.sh
```

5. Make the script file execute at each start-up either by adding it to your Startup Applications through the GUI or by placing a `Modify_Multimedia_Keys.desktop` file in the `~/.config/autostart/` directory that contains the following content replacing `YOUR_USERNAME` with your actual username:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=/home/YOUR_USERNAME/.Modify_Multimedia_Keys.sh
Hidden=false
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
Name=Modify Multimedia Keys
Comment=This modifies keyboard multimedia keys
```

---

**Notice:**

For more information and other ways of detecting or remapping keys, please refer to **[this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1200910/968501)**.

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at the `solaar` package: `apt install solaar`. This package is designed for use mainly with Logitech wireless keyboards and mice, but also supports some other USB keyboards, sometimes with limited functionality.

It has a function to swap the Fx keys:

[image]

If you have any success, please consider contributing here: https://pwr-solaar.github.io/Solaar/devices

If this doesn't work, consider building the latest version with the instructions here: https://pwr-solaar.github.io/Solaar/installation

Comment: I tried solaar already. My keyboard is not recognized.

Comment: Worked for mew with a K400, thanks

Comment: This seems like a super useful app, I updated the comment to also added a screenshot of the relevant feature to swap Fx keys. However, on Ubuntu 22.04 with my MX Keys it somehow did not have any effect and the function keys still trigger the media key action instead of the function number.

Comment: thanks! It works for my K380 under Ubuntu 22.04