# using multimedia-like key in xkb layout

Tags: keyboard-layout, xkb

If I want to redefine say R key, I use:

```
key <AD04>  { [         r,          R,      Page_Up,     registered ]};
```

corresponding xev output for that key is:

```
KeyPress event, serial 35, synthetic NO, window 0x5a00001,
    root 0x228, subw 0x0, time 96963419, (121,378), root:(992,832),
    state 0x10, keycode 27 (keysym 0x72, r), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (72) "r"
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (72) "r"
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

How did I found `AD04`? I was looking into existing mappings and find `r`, easy.

But then there are more exotic characters, like `BKSL` for backspace, or `LSGT` which is "weird" backslash for iso keyboards (IIUC). So how did I found out `LSGT`? I know, that it's typically to be found on gb keyboards. Not very correct way of looking for it, but at least possible.

So now I'd like to re-define key for some multimedia-like key on MS-ergonomic 4000. The xev looks like this:

```
KeyRelease event, serial 39, synthetic NO, window 0x4800001,
    root 0x228, subw 0x0, time 97354466, (-387,623), root:(484,1077),
    state 0x10, keycode 167 (keysym 0x1008ff27, XF86Forward), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

how do I find: `key <XY05>` or what is it? Or what can I use in place of `<XY05>`, similarly as we can use `U200E` to print arbitrary unicode if keysym is missing? This keyboard abuses F-keys higher than 12 for lost of multimedia-like keys, so I assume this will be the same and actually usable, but which!, how to find it?

---

update: partially found it, does not work for all keys.

Regarding symbol `r`:

from example, in xev listing there is `keycode 27`. Well I'm not that convinced, that this is indeed *keycode*, as `showkey -k` says `r` is `19`, and it's not scancode or ascii either, and that's all codes I know about. Anyways, this *whatever* is 27. Pairing from *whatever* to `<whatever>` is done in: `/usr/share/X11/xkb/keycodes`, so issue `find ./ -type f -exec grep -l 27 {} +` and you will find pairing.

However some keys, in my case XF86Forward and defined duplicately in keycodes files, and neither `<WHATEVER>` works. Attempts to define custom xkb_keycodes ends up in errors (xkb is not that well written/documented). Anywys as a ugly workaround, one can use xmodmap to redefine the key, and then use in xkb some other key, which actually works.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/a/1200910/968501

Comment: @Raffa thanks. But this is doing the opposite IIUC. The hard part is finding `key <KEY_CODE>`. I cannot define/find it. I have keycode as reported by xev, but I don't know how to write it into xkb. In my case, it's "keycode 167", I found it defined in evdev as <I167> and in xfree86 as <I27> but neither works. No idea how to proceed.

Comment: opposite, apologies ...  kindly see this: https://askubuntu.com/a/1313977/968501