# Map function keys on 65% keyboard

Tags: keyboard, function-keys

I'm new to Linux in general and Ubuntu in particular and I just have a little problem (well a lot, but step by step :P).

I've got a 65% keyboard, an Ozone Tactical to be precise ([this](https://www.ozonegaming.com/es/product/tactical)). I really like this keyboard and I used it for a couple of years in Windows without problems.

But now, in Ubuntu, when I try to press my Fn key + any number in order to execute a Fx key (for example Fn + 2 => F2) Ubuntu thinks I'm trying to change screen brightness, keyboard brightness or changing volume.

I'm not talking about setting precedence to Fn keys or "special" keys, I just don't have those keys :) I want they to behave as numbers if I don't press Fn and as function keys when I press it.

Ah, I almost forgot: If I enter BIOS, I can use Fn + number as function key with no problem at all.

Thank you very much in advance :)

PS: If it isn't possible with fn key I don't mind create new shorcuts like Windows key + number to get function keys work if it's possible.

Comment: For a while I've got downvotes in my question... Why? Is there something super-obvious I am missing? Sorry if so, and thanks in advance if you help me :)

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/q/1200893/968501

Answer (score 0):

You can try with

```
echo 0 | sudo tee /sys/module/hid_apple/parameters/fnmode
```

For more details check: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AppleKeyboard#Change_Function_Key_behavior